# Change password on postgresql in a qnap nas

Tags: postgresql-9.3, qnap

I have a postgresql database 9.3.4 installed on a qnap nas. I would like to change the postgres password but I can not.
I log in with phpPgAdmin and, in a sql window, I write:

```
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'mynewpassword'
```

The query is executed correctly but the password does not change, even after restarting the nas. What could be the problem?
The same operation I did on my pc windows and it worked fine.

Comment: can you share what is the performance when datafile is mounted on NAS?

Comment: Thanks, but all this time I changed nas.
Regards.